# Media Tags regex code needed for modified YouTube links in Invision Power Board

Tags: regex, youtube, invision-power-board

IPBoard already comes with relevant regex codes for regular YouTube links. I need help with a different kind of YouTube links that are sent through subscription update emails. Here are some example links:

```
http://youtube.com/attribution_link?a=r_FgjB-RKNo&u=/watch%3Fv%3DB0_X8zWJd0Q%26feature%3Dem-uploademail (B0_X8zWJd0Q)
http://youtube.com/attribution_link?a=1crTn2Lx38I&u=/watch%3Fv%3DHhebhh2s5d4%26feature%3Dem-uploademail (Hhebhh2s5d4)
http://youtube.com/attribution_link?a=_zMgiznzBto&u=/watch%3Fv%3D-kaoCPvUHJM%26feature%3Dem-uploademail (-kaoCPvUHJM)
http://youtube.com/attribution_link?a=F8VReY1sT0A&u=/watch%3Fv%3D5RLM9rk0Q8s%26feature%3Dem-uploademail (5RLM9rk0Q8s)
```

The code in the brackets at the end is the relevant YouTube video ID. `attribution_link?a=` seems to include random digits for different videos.

Here is what IPBoard backend shows:

Existing regex structure for regular YouTube links:

```
http(?:s)?://(www.)?youtube.com/watch\?(\S+?)?v=([\d\w-_]+?)(&\S+?)?
```

This converts to:

```
<iframe id="ytplayer" class="EmbeddedVideo" type="text/html" width="640" height="390" src="http://youtube.com/embed/$3?html5=1&fs=1" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen webkitallowfullscreen /></iframe>
```

IPBoard Guidelines::

**Media Replacement Match**

Example Link: `http://www.test.com/23423/`

Match: `http://www.test.com/{1}/`

**Media Replacement HTML**

`You can use $1, $2, etc as variable replacements.`

Example Link: `<a href="http://www.testm.com/$1/">$1</a>`

Result: `<a href="http://www.testm.com/23423/">23423</a>`

Answer (score 0):

**Updated** expression to handle embedded urlencoded links:

```
youtube.*?watch.*?v(?:%25|=)([\d\w-_]+)
```

Example: http://regex101.com/r/fO6qE5

---

**Old**:

```
http(?:s)?:\/\/(?:www\.)?youtube\.com\/.*?watch%3Fv%([\d\w-_]+)
```

Example: http://regex101.com/r/cX9rP2

Comment: Your code is capturing the text after `attribution_link?a=` bit... This text appears to be random and is not connected to the YouTube video ID... Video ID is after `&u=/watch%3Fv%3D` part with `%26feature%3Dem-uploademail` at the end. Thanks!

Comment: Does not appear to work. I replaced the expression on your regex101.com entry and even that did not show the correct data fetching. This is how I have added the data in IPB backend: http://imgur.com/xOTV33u.png

Thanks!

Comment: Ah, you know it might be the capture groups. It was retrieving capture group 2 not 1. Try now/

Comment: Does not work. Not sure if I am entering data in IP.Board wrong. The link does not embed at all. I mean the link is not even turning into a broken YouTube player. http://goo.gl/1eAnbU Thanks.

Comment: Ok, not sure at all how to do what you're asking -- can you update your question with steps to reproduce and test? Oh, nevermind I see now.

Comment: Ok. I think a JavaScript code on the forum caused confusion.

`http://broadbandforum.co/offer.php?link=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.youtube.com%2Fattribution_link%3Fa%3DfF1CWYwxCQ4%26u%3D%2Fwatch%253Fv%253DqYr8opTPSaQ%2526feature%253Dem-uploademail` 

is not the linked YouTube link. The offers.php thing is appended at run time and is not related to embedding code.

Comment: Yeah, either way I put a conditional in there that will either look for the urlencoded `= -> %25` or actual `=`.